# Curve in a disk

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, plane-curves

I take a curve $\vec\gamma:[a,b]\longrightarrow \Delta$, where $\Delta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is the disk of radius $r>0$. If the curve has length $L>0$ does exist an upper bound (in terms of $r$ and $L$) for the curvature of the curve?

Any reference is very appreciated.

**EDIT:** The answer of John Hughes has solved the problem.

Now, what happen if the curve is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the curve 
$$
\gamma(t) = (s \cos t, s \sin t), 0 \le t \le \frac{L}{2\pi s}
$$
where $s < r$. its curvature is $\frac{1}{s}$, which is clearly unbounded.

If you don't like that the path intersects itself, just make $s$ a very slowly increasing function  of $t$ with mean $S$. Then the curvature will be approximately $\frac{1}{S}$.

Comment: Thanks. Good example. What happen if I take a closed curve?

Comment: Equally bad: You wind around the origin, as above, at radius near $S$, for $L/2$ units of distance, make a hairpin turn, and follow your tracks back again, at a slightly smaller radius, and then make another hairpin turn to complete the path with length approximately $L$; small adjustments can thne make it have length $L$.  The curvature along most of the path is about $1/S$, except at the hairpin turns, where it's much higher. Hence: no upper bound.

Comment: By the way...adding conditions after you've gotten an answer really isn't a good idea, as it tends to make the answers appear inadequate. Ask a new question instead. See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions